# Why is the intercept not the mean at the continuous predictor being zero?

Tags: r, lme4, intercept

In the book of Gelman&Hill it is described that when you fit a linear regression with one continuous predictor, then the intercept should represent the predicted outcome when the predictor==0. Sometimes this can make sense, sometimes not (or only with somehow scaled predictor). If the predictor is a factor, then the intercept should reflect the mean at the reference category (at least when using dummy codes). I am currently working with the sleepstudy data and I do not understand what is going on because here this is not the case. Although I encountered the problem in a linear mixed model, it also shows up in a linear model:

In the example below (fit), the intercept is 251.41 whereas we can see that the mean at Days == 0 is 256.65. When I convert the predictor into a factor, everything works as expected. What am I missing? For the linear mixed model I want the intercept to reflect the mean at day 5 but keep the variable Days a numerical variable. The problem occurs there, too. It also occurs in another dataset I have where there is an equal sample size for each day. I feel like I miss something that is super easy or obvious but I can't get it...

```
library(lme4)
library(tidyverse)
fit <- lm(Reaction ~ Days, sleepstudy)
summary(fit)
group_by(sleepstudy, Days) %>% summarise(means=mean(Reaction))
sleepstudy$Days_discrete <- as.factor(sleepstudy$Days)
fit2 <- lm(Reaction ~ Days_discrete, sleepstudy)
summary(fit2)
```

Comment: I have no idea about what you mean by "_For the linear mixed model I want the intercept to reflect the mean at day 5 but keep the variable Days a numerical variable._". You can center the variable such that zero is at day 5 but I do not think this is what you want.

Comment: Look at how the intercept (i.e. the point where the slope meets the  yaxis) is calculated) - `mean(sleepstudy$Reaction) - 10.467 * mean(sleepstudy$Days)
#[1] 251.4064`  and i n the second case, the default level is at 0 level, so `mean(sleepstudy$Reaction[sleepstudy$Days_discrete == 0])#
[1] 256.6518`

Comment: With one continuous predictor, the intercept, as you say, represents the **predicted** value when the continuous predictor is 0. Not the *observed* value, the *predicted* value, which uses information from other values as well and assumes a linear relationship.

Comment: @BenjaminChristoffersen yeah that is what I meant. However, the mean of Days is 4.5. Thus, if I center it, then day 5 would get `5 - 4.5 = 0.5`. So, what you meant was subtracting 5 from each value, correct? Because then day 5 would be reflected by zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I missing?

`fit1` should not necessarily cross the origin at the mean of the `Days` with value zero. It is the best fitting line if `Days` has a linear effect. See the formulas for [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Fitting_the_regression_line).

`fit2` should due to the default contrast setup in R. It also does so

```r
library(lme4)
tapply(sleepstudy$Reaction, sleepstudy$Days, mean)
     0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9 
#R> 256.6518 264.4958 265.3619 282.9920 288.6494 308.5185 312.1783 318.7506 336.6295 350.8512 
fit1 <- lm(Reaction ~ Days, sleepstudy)
coef(fit1)
#R> (Intercept)        Days 
#R>   251.40510    10.46729 
fit2 <- lm(Reaction ~ as.factor(Days), sleepstudy)
coef(fit2)
#R>      (Intercept) as.factor(Days)1 as.factor(Days)2 as.factor(Days)3 as.factor(Days)4 as.factor(Days)5 as.factor(Days)6 
#R>       256.651806         7.843950         8.710094        26.340206        31.997617        51.866650        55.526450 
#R> as.factor(Days)7 as.factor(Days)8 as.factor(Days)9 
#R>        62.098778        79.977700        94.199417
```